# converting a list of string to clickable link

Tags: r, hyperlink, shiny, href, dashboard

I want to do something similiar to part 2.9 of the {http://rstudio.github.io/DT/}. I'm able to get the output correct that is ("[RStudio](http://rstudio.com)" and Hello) but not a clikable (RStudio and Hello)

```
    m = matrix(c(
   '<b>Bold</b>', '<em>Emphasize</em>', '<a href="http://rstudio.com">RStudio</a>',
   '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'Hello World\');">Hello</a>'
    ), 2)
    colnames(m) = c('<span style="color:red">Column 1</span>', '<em>Column 2</em>')
 datatable(m)  # escape = TRUE by default
```

my output is

`<b>Bold</b>   <a href="http://rstudio.com">RStudio</a>`
`<em>Emphasize</em> <a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello World');">Hello</a>`

My desired output is:

**Bold**      |  [RStudio](http://rstudio.com)

*Emphasize*|  Hello

I'm using the below code for my DT:

```
mydata$url <- paste0("<a href='",mydata$url,"' target='_blank'>",mydata$url,"</a>")
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Have you tried `datatable(m, escape = FALSE)` like the other example on that page? Because that should allow the HTML to be interpreted as HTML and your links to be clickable.

Comment: @Marius, I got it thanks, I got the correct place to keep my escape function.